# Chances of admission/how to overcome limited research experience

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

applying to PhD programs this coming cycle (MIT, Stanford + a few others) and wanted some advice on how to make up for lack of publications. Some details have been intentionally left vague:

Raw application info:

I work in NLP and will be applying with an emphasis on specific subfields that I am particularly interested in

4.0 GPA from top Ivy League math + cs program

Currently doing NLP in industry org (i.e Google Brain, FAIR, Microsoft Research). Nothing published yet but leading a project internally and results are good

Probably not going to take GRE due to COVID and also busy at work (I am only applying to programs that don't require)

Did ugrad thesis in NLP, nothing crazy but was good experience

Have some strong open source ML software contributions

Rec letters from math professor who was my ugrad thesis reader (will be more superficial, got an A in his class), thesis advisor with 50k+ citations in NLP (strong, also got an A in his class), and current research manager from industry that I work closely with (strong)

My publications are sadly non-existent so far which is what concerns me. I also have no fellowships or similar things of the sort. I decided I wanted to go for the PhD at a pretty late stage in my ugrad career and would love to hear about how to address that aspect and/or if there are any other potential things to look out for. Thanks in advance for any advice, it is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Your record seems pretty good. I’m sure if you thesis supervisor gives you a good recommendation you’ll be fine. The only way you can get more publications is by doing the research needed to get the publications. You could always take a year off and try get something published if you think that will help your chances.

Comment: Publications are not (and in my opinion, should never be) necessary for a successful PhD application. A bonus, yes, but not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have an undergrad degree, then lack of publications, alone, isn't likely to be the major block to getting accepted *somewhere*. But if your search for a program is too narrow then the competition (by many) for too few slots will wreck your chances. I suggest, only, that you widen your search to other R1 universities that have larger programs and larger faculties. Don't constrain your search to, say, only the top 50 US institutions. There are a lot of fine places with a lot of fine faculty.

Maybe it just forms a backstop, but you should probably have one.